# Move objects automatically

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The objective of my exercise is to create a game in which a falling ball needs to be caught by a bar at the bottom of the screen. Below code does not make the ball to fall automatically. I referred to below posts, but could not find a solution:
[Tkinter bind to arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824005/tkinter-bind-to-arc), [Automatically Moving Shape? Python 3.5 Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778520/automatically-moving-shape-python-3-5-tkinter)

```
import tkinter as tk


class Game(tk.Tk):
     def __init__(self):
         tk.Tk.__init__(self)
         self.can = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400)
         self.can.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         self.ball = self.can.create_oval(40, 40, 60, 60, fill="red", tag="ball")
         self.player = self.can.create_rectangle(300,345,350,360, fill="red")
         self.bind("<Key>", self.move_player)
         self.can.tag_bind("ball",self.move_b)
         self.mainloop()

    def move_b(self,event=None):
         self.can.move(self.ball, 1, 0)
         print(self.ball)
         # move again after 25ms (0.025s)
         self.can.after(25, self.move_b)

    def move_player(self, event):
        key = event.keysym
        if key == "Left":
           self.can.move(self.player, -20, 0)
        elif key == "Right":
            self.can.move(self.player, 20, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
Game()
```

Comment: Please fix indentation errors.

Answer (score 0):

2nd positional argument to [`tag_bind`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_bind-method) is an event, whereas in your code it's passed as the actual callback, `self.move_b`. First, add an event:

```
self.can.tag_bind("ball", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.move_b)
```

If you don't want it to have event, simply pass `None`:

```
self.can.tag_bind("ball", None, self.move_b)
```

or don't use `tag_bind` at all, and simply call:

```
self.move_b()
```

Whenever you want the animation to start.